# boost built project on i386 fails to link

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, x86-64, i386

I am using a project named "GenericMod" which internally uses boost library 1.58.0.

Previously the boost 1.58 was compiled on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga)

whose gcc -v output was as follows

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --disable-plugin --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/jre --with-cpu=generic --host=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55)
```

It was compiled using the following command

```
./b2 install -a --includedir=testbuild/include --libdir=testbuild/lib --layout=system variant=release target-os=linux link=static runtime-link=static address-model=32 cxxflags=-fPIC
```

Now, when the project "GenericMod" was build, on the same machine, build was successful and there was no error.

But recently the build environment was changed. The project is being built in a new machine now which is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.9 (Tikanga)

and its gcc -v output

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: i386-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --disable-plugin --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/jre --with-cpu=generic --host=i386-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)
```

When the project is built in this machine now, i was getting linker errors (probably as the boost libraries were built on a different environment).

So i built the boost 1.58.0 in this machine again with the same build command.

```
./b2 install -a --includedir=testbuild/include --libdir=testbuild/lib --layout=system variant=release target-os=linux link=static runtime-link=static address-model=32 cxxflags=-fPIC
```

Now when the project is built in this machine, my understanding is that there shouldnt be any error and the build should go through link phase.

But the linker error still occurs.

```
libboost_thread.a(thread.o): In function `boost::thread::physical_concurrency()':
thread.cpp:(.text+0x2084): undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
```

Can someone please explain why is this happening ? I have been breaking my head past week for this and couldn;t get enough explanation in other places.

Should i include some flag to specify the build for i386?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just FYI, your compiler is almost 10 years old.  gcc7.3 can optimize better, especially for current hardware (`-march=native`) but also better code in general, for old and new hardware.  (gcc8.1 has some very nice improvements, but it's still very new.)

Comment: Are you building boost and the final project with the same C++ standard library implementation and version of that C++ standard library?

Comment: @PeterT Yes, I built boost in the same system and then the application in the same system.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thats true. But this is the build environment we have in our project. We are supposed to use this system

Comment: @PeterT  Any idea if something to be done for i386-redhat-linux ? Do we need a ny specific tag to build boost on this target? -arch  i386 doesn't work.

Comment: `-m32` is 32-bit code.  `-march=native` or whatever would just be a tuning option.  Unless Boost is checking CPP macros for `#ifdef __SSE2__` or something, then enabling more stuff shouldn't matter.  That seems unlikely for `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const`, more likely your C++ standard libraries are too old.  (So installing + using a newer g++ might actually help.)

Comment: @PeterCordes none of the options worked . i dont know why. i used -m32 and -march=native. still same link errors.  The system on which i am running this boost and the application gives the below output for uname -p -o i686 GNU/Linux. Should i used i686 or i386 in some option to b2?